# how to set ColorPickerSlider element, ColorChannel Property in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

[image]I Don't know,how to set colorChannel property of ColorPickerSlider dynamically in c#.I need ColorPickerSlider like the picture i added,based on color choosen from colorSpectrum.I don't Want to use ColorPicker Element.I need this as Separate Component.

```
ColorSpectrum ColorSpectrum = new ColorSpectrum();
ColorPickerSlider ColorPickerSlider = new ColorPickerSlider();
ColorPickerSlider.ColorChannel=???????;
```

Comment: anybody know the solution???

Comment: Hello, `ColorPickerSlider.ColorChannel` is an enumerated property, which only plays a role of identification. Modifying it will not affect the value of `ColorSpectrum`. In C# code, you can directly assign a value to it, such as `ColorPickerSlider.ColorChannel = ColorPickerHsvChannel.Value`.

Comment: then,how can i create this type of slider,based on color selected from colorspectrum in uwp??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of style, we can consider a combined approach:

`Rectangle` + `ColorPickerSlider`

Use `Rectangle` as the background and `ColorPickerSlider` as the actual function slider.

```xml
<Grid Width="300" Height="40">
    <Rectangle Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" x:Name="BackgroundRect"/>
    <ColorPickerSlider ColorChannel="Hue" Style="{StaticResource ColorPickerSliderStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Modify Rectangle background color**

```cs
var stopCollection = new GradientStopCollection();
stopCollection.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Colors.Black, Offset=0 });
stopCollection.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Colors.Purple, Offset=1 });
var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(stopCollection,0);
BackgroundRect.Fill = brush;
```

[image: 01.png]

**ColorPickerSliderStyle**

```xml
<Style x:Key="ColorPickerSliderStyle" TargetType="ColorPickerSlider">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ColorPickerSliderThumbBackground}" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="4" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HorizontalThumb.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ColorPickerSliderThumbBackgroundPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="HorizontalThumb.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ColorPickerSliderThumbBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="HorizontalTrackRect.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ColorPickerSliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="HorizontalDecreaseRect.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ColorPickerSliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HorizontalThumb.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ColorPickerSliderThumbBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusEngagementStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusDisengaged" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedHorizontal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SliderContainer.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Target="HorizontalThumb.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="True" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedVertical">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SliderContainer.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Target="VerticalThumb.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="True" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForeground}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeFontWeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeMargin}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                    <Grid x:Name="SliderContainer" Background="Transparent" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" MinHeight="44">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="18" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="18" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="Transparent" Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0" />
                            <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Height="24" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" Width="8">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="ToolTip" VerticalOffset="20" />
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            </Thumb>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

Update

**About calculating gradient color**

We have two colors: black and purple:

Black (RGB) : 0 0 0

Purple (RGB): 128 0 128

Let ’s assume that the Thumb of `ColorPickerSlider` is in the middle, with a value of 50 (the maximum value of Slider is 100)

So we can get the middle color as (RGB) 64 0 64

Comment: its working fine,but i want the excet rectangle hexadecimalcolor when the ColorPickerslider is moved.

Comment: Hi, this is the internal data processing of `ColorPickerSlider`. Unless a `CustomColorPickerSlider` is rewritten, the display content of the `Tooltip` may not be changed.

Comment: then how can i,get the colorpickerslider color when it is sliding??

Comment: This is just a visual change. In fact, you can get the current value through `ColorPickerSlider.Value`, but it can not intuitively reflect the color of the `Thumb` position. You need to calculate based on the value combined with the colors at both ends. In this regard, you can find information about calculating gradient colors online

Comment: can you suggest me,how to calculate?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate,help me to calculate?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide a simple idea to calculate by RGB value of color